# Lodash sort incorrect with Alphanumberic?

Tags: lodash

I'm using lodash to sort Array.

Ex:

```
    const arr = [ { name: 'Card 2' }, { name: 'Card 1' }, { name: 'Card 10' }]
```

Sort:

```
    lodash.orderBy(arr, ['name'], ['asc'])
```

Result:

```
    [{ name: 'Card 1' }, { name: 'Card 10' }, { name: 'Card 2' }]
```

How I can resolve it?
My expect the result should be:

```
   [ { name: 'Card 1' }, { name: 'Card 2' }, { name: 'Card 10' }]
```

Comment: It's performing lexicographical sorting, so `"10" < "2"` the same way `"az" < "b"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. You are sorting lexicographically. Just like the "aardvark" goes after "a" and before "b", so does "10" go after "1" but before "2". If you want to sort it numerically, you would need to extract the number.

Here, I split each array into alphabetic and numeric portions, then pad the numeric portions with zeroes so that they can be compared like strings (e.g. `"Card 0000000000000010"`):

```js
const arr = [ { name: 'Card 2' }, { name: 'Card 1' }, { name: 'Card 10' }, { name: 'Document 1' }]
const sortedArr = _.sortBy(arr, [function(o) {
  const split = o.name.split(/\b(\d+)\b/);
  for (let i = 1; i < split.length; i += 2) {
    split[i] = split[i].padStart(16, '0');
  }
  return split.join('');
}]);
console.log(sortedArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lodash dont have the options to sort numberic? Extract the number is bad. Sometimes the name don't have number

Comment: I tried copy your code to local (NodeJS v10.15.3, lodash latest version 4.17.15 ) But result is wrong

Comment: [ { name: 'Card 1' },
  { name: 'Card 10' },
  { name: 'Card 2' },
  { name: 'Document 1' } ]

Comment: The first or second one? I'm pretty confident the second one should work.... EDIT: Actually, I just saw the first one does not - I don't know why I was getting a different result before. I'll just delete the first one, and leave up the one I know works.

Comment: I'm wrong, I copied first one. Second one working well. Thanks very much

Comment: Cheers. Note that this will not do the right thing for negative numbers, floating point numbers etc - more logic would be required.

Comment: Ok, negative number and float number won't appears

Answer (score 1):

If you expect your items to have numbers only at the end, then you can define your own sorting comparator and perform the following logic:

1. Take any part of the item *before* from the beginning until any number from each item and compare them alphabetically.
2. If equal, then compare the numbers from the end numerically.

To do this, you can just pass two iteratees to [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#orderBy):

1. You can easily achieve that with the `/^[^\d]*/` regex.
2. That can be done using the `/\d*$/` regex and converting to a number.

```js
const arr = [ { name: 'Card 2' }, { name: 'Card 1' }, { name: 'Card 10' }, { name: 'Alpha 2' }, { name: 'Alpha 1' }, { name: 'Alpha 10' }, { name: 'Beta 2' }, { name: 'Beta 1' }, { name: 'Beta' }, { name: '2' }, { name: '1' }, { name: '10' },{ name: 'Gamma' }, { name: 'Delta' },]

const extractString = item => item.name.match(/^[^\d]*/)[0];
const extractNumber = item => Number(item.name.match(/\d*$/)[0]);

const sorted = _.orderBy(arr, [extractString, extractNumber], ['asc']);

console.log(sorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How about a string have many numbers
Ex: const arr = [ { name: 'WJB 1 - Card 2' }, { name: 'WJB 1 - Card 1' }, { name: 'WJB 10 - Card 10' }, { name: 'WJB -2 Alpha 2' }, { name: 'Alpha 1' }, { name: 'Alpha 10' }, { name: 'Beta 2' }, { name: 'Beta 1' }, { name: 'Beta' }, { name: '2' }, { name: '1' }, { name: '10' },{ name: 'Gamma' }, { name: 'Delta' }]

Comment: Then that is a lot harder. You'd need to do an even more custom sorting where you manually compare each two items and look for where they start to differ in content, chop there and check if the *next* part is a number or not and parse it as such, if it is. But that becomes a bigger task that I don't think Lodash is suitable for. The iteratees you give to `orderBy` only depend on one element, whereas you need to take into account two. This is easier done with ordinary `.sort` than `_.sortBy` or `_.orderBy`.